# Use CMSensorRecorder to continuously collect Accelerometer data in Apple Watch

Tags: background, accelerometer, apple-watch

I want to use *CMSensorRecorder* to **continuously** collect the Accelerometer data, also if user didn't open my app on watch\phone.

What I want to do is - "whenever possible" (i.e. watch is awake and I can execute code), do the following:

- call *recordAccelerometerForDuration* to tell watch to keep collecting data for as long as possible
- call *accelerometerDataFromDate* to get data collected so far (or from last time I got the data)

My question is - how to implement the "whenever possible", i.e. how can I cause my watch application to wake up and execute these apis whenever the watch itself wakes up ?

Answer (score 1):

CMSensorRecorder- to recored data continuously use ExtentionDelegate to triger CMSensorRecorder to invoke start recording and  reading data.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        print("Active")

        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        AccelorometerDataReader.sharedReader.sessionEndDate = Date()
        AccelorometerDataReader.sharedReader.getRecordedData()
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.

        print("inactive")
        AccelorometerDataReader.sharedReader.startReadingAccelorometerData()
        AccelorometerDataReader.sharedReader.sessionStartDate = Date()


    }
```

//AccelorometerReaderCode

```
   func startReadingAccelorometerData()
    {
        if CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable()
        {
            if CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording()
            {
                print("Authorized.......")
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
                    {
                        self.recorder?.recordAccelerometer(forDuration: 3 * 60)  // Record for 3 minutes
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("not authorized")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("NOt available for recording")
        }
    }


    func getRecordedData()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
            {
                if self.sessionStartDate < self.sessionEndDate
                {
                    if   let list  =  self.recorder?.accelerometerData(from: self.sessionStartDate, to:self.sessionEndDate)
                    {
                        for record in list
                        {
                            let data = record as! CMRecordedAccelerometerData
                            print("x: \(data.acceleration.x) y: \(data.acceleration.y) z: \(data.acceleration.z) time :\(data.startDate.getFormattedDate())")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem you can.  I have tried the following but none of these really work.

Register for backgroundApplicationRefresh (watchOS 3) and make sure the app is saved to the Dock. Dock apps can rely on getting one call an hour to update themselves.

On completion of the period query for the accelerometer data and archive the result to file and then transfer the file to the iOS companion app.  The file transfer will occur in the background independent of the watch kit app assuming you get enough CPU time to write the accelerometer data to file.

Try using ProcessInfo API to keep the process running.

To date the only success I have had is in running an async thread to extract the data and keeping the watch kit app active by tapping on the screen each time the screen blanks.

Hope this helps and please post any better solution you find.

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I didn't find a better solution.